# Google chart visualization with rangepicker

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[i need to change google DateRangeFilter by daterangepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTOIb.png).
I would like to use daterange picker + google visualization +filtering by categorie. I do not see any graphic. I get a blank page. I do not see where the error comes from my code. Please someone can help me please?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages : ['controls'] } );

    $(function() {

    // Set the default dates
    var startDate = Date.create().addDays(-6), // 7 days ago
        endDate = Date.create();                // today

    var range = $('#range');

    // Show the dates in the range input
    range.val(startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}') + ' - ' + endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'));

    // Load chart
    createTable(startDate, endDate);

    range.daterangepicker({
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        ranges: {
            'Today': ['today', 'today'],
            'Yesterday': ['yesterday', 'yesterday'],
            'Last 7 Days': [Date.create().addDays(-6), 'today'],
            'Last 30 Days': [Date.create().addDays(-29), 'today']
        }
    }, function(start, end) {

        createTable(start, end);

    });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(createTable);

    function createTable() {
      // Create the dataset (DataTable)

              var jsonData = $.ajax({

                url: 'http://getdata',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{ start: startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'), end : endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}')},
                dataType: 'json'

              }).done(function (results) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('datetime', 'Performance_year');
                //data.addColumn('number', 'Performance_mac');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Performance_expense');



                $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                  data.addRow([(new Date(row.performance_year)),parseInt(row.performance_expense)]);
                });

      // Create a dashboard.
      var dash_container = document.getElementById('dashboard_div'),
        myDashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dash_container);

     // Define category pickers for 'Companies'
      var myFields = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'company_div',
          'options': {
              'filterColumnLabel': 'Performance_expense',
              'ui': {
                  'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                  'allowTyping': false,
                  'allowMultiple': false

              }
          },
          'state': {
              selectedValues: ['Performance_expenses']
          }
      });



       // Define category pickers for 'Companies'
      var myDate = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'date_div',
          'options': {
              'filterColumnLabel': 'Performance_year',
              'ui': {
                  'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                  'allowTyping': false,
                  'allowMultiple': false

              }
          },
          'state': {
              selectedValues: ['Performance_year']
          }
      });



      // Table visualization
      var myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType' : 'Table',
        'containerId' : 'table_div'
      });

     /*
        var myLine = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType' : 'LineChart',
        'containerId' : 'line_div',
      });*/

       var myLine = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'BarChart',
        'containerId': 'line_div',
        'options': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 500
        },
        'view': {
            'columns': [1, 1]
        }
    });


      // Bind myTable to the dashboard, and to the controls
      // this will make sure our table is update when our date changes
      myDashboard.bind(myFields, myDate);
      // Line chart visualization  
      // Bind myLine to the dashboard, and to the controls
      // this will make sure our line chart is update when our date changes
      myDashboard.bind(myDate, [myLine, myTable]);
      myDashboard.draw(data);
    });
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="dashboard_div">
    <div id="date_div" style="height: 100px; float:right"><!-- Controls renders here --></div>
    <input type="text" name="range" id="range" style="border:none; width:150px;font-size:12px; height:40px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="company_div" ><!-- Controls renders here --></div>
    <div id="line_div" style="height: 500px; border: 1"><!-- Line chart renders here --></div>
    <div id="table_div" style="height: 500px; width: 600px; border: 1 ;float:right"><!-- Table renders here --></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The daterange picker bootstrap plugin -->
<script src="assets/js/sugar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/daterangepicker.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone can help me please!

Comment: couple issues -- __1)__ the [dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboard) `bind` method accepts ControlWrapper(s) as the first argument, ChartWrapper(s) as the second. here, ControlWrappers are being passed as both --> `myDashboard.bind(myFields, myDate);` -- __2)__ arguments are being passed to `createTable`, but the function doesn't define any arguments -- also recommend __not using__ `jsapi` -- according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) --> Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

Comment: Please @WhiteHat i changed the code like this.

Comment: Please @WhiteHat i changed the code . but i have a same problem...
Please  can you test my codes 
My biggest problem is how to get the
Daterangepicker (from input value) + filter by category and send the set values to google chart.
My data come from Postgres in JSON

Comment: remove this line, which has no closing bracket --> `$(function() {`

Comment: i add this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTOIb.png and test your proposition, Finally I see why blank page.but 
The real problem is to replace google Daterangefilter by daterangepicker from INPUT.
I added a picture in the first question...thank you for your help